# Java implment binary search tree with iterator for Key only

Tags: java

I meet a problem with Java programming. I would like to implement a class (binary search tree) as

```
public class ABC<Key, Value> implements Iterator<Key>
{
}
```

In this class I defined a node called ABCNode with the structure as follow:

```
public class ABCNode
{
    public Key key;
    public Value value;
    public ABCNode left;
    public ABCNode right;
}
```

I then wrote the follow code

```
public Iterable<Key> iterator()
{
    return new ABCKeyIterator();
}

private class ABCKeyIterator implements Iterator<Key>
{
    public boolean hasNext() {}
    public void remove() {}
    public Key next() {}   
}
```

The class includes Key Value pair. Now I would like to implement a iterator function to get all the keys. I got an error with iterator function

```
iterator() in ABC cannot implement iterator() in Iterable return type Iterable<Key> is not compatible with Iterator<Key> where Key,T are type-variables: Key extends Comparable<Key> declared in class ABC T extends Object declared in interface Iterable
```

Can anyone help to see how to implement it from scratch? I think Java has already had such thing. But I would like to implement it by myself to learn it. Thank you.

Comment: Is your ABC class simply a key-value pair class? Then the iterator would iterate over a single value?

Comment: I have linked list in ABC. I call it ABCNode, it is Key key, Value value, ABCNode left, ABCNode right.

Comment: Why can't you just return the iterator of the linked list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error-message is complaining about this line:

```
public Iterable<Key> iterator()
```

where you've declared `iterator()` as returning `Iterable<Key>` rather than `Iterator<Key>`. The two interfaces, while related, are completely different.

Comment: Thank you ruakh, I think I should return Iterator<Key> for function iterator().